# hdfs connection failure

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I know this question has been discussed many time, but none of the solutions worked for me. I am still getting this error.

hadoop version is 2.0.2-alpha

```
$ jps
24107 NameNode
24314 DataNode
25299 Jps
24720 NodeManager
24520 ResourceManager

$ hdfs dfs ... any command gives me this error 
<command>: Call from jeet/192.168.1.26 to jeet:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connectionrefused;
```

---

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9620       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58932           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24720/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      26020/vsftpd
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1610/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      614/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      713/cupsd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50010           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24314/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9210       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24107/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50075           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24314/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9600       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50020           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24314/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9220       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24107/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8040            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24720/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9610       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8042            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24720/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24720/java
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.26:9200       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24107/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      614/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::23                   :::*                    LISTEN      11765/xinetd

--------------------- core-site.xml

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://jeet:9000</value>
    <description>
      The name of the default file system.  Either the
      literal string "local" or a host:port for NDFS.
    </description>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>360</value>
    <description>Number of minutes between trash checkpoints.
      If zero, the trash feature is disabled.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.groups.cache.secs</name>
    <value>14400</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
    <description>
     Temporary directories.
    </description>
  </property>
```

Comment: please share the code that results in this error.

Comment: he's not running any code. he's just trying to run the cli.

Comment: please run a `sudo netstat -atnp | grep LISTEN` and post that back so we can see what ports are open

Comment: I have updated the netstat output along with core-site.xml configuration. If you see I am not seeing port 9000, all other ports used are there - 9200,9210,9220,9600,9610,9620. I don't see 9000 from core-site.xml and 9400 from mapred-site.xml. No errors in logs and jps shows them running. Thanks for you time and help.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info to look into.